# What shifters do I have to buy to fit Shimano MT200 hydraulic brakes?

Tags: shimano, hydraulic-disc-brake

i want to change my brakes from mechanical disk brake to hydraulics, as right now the braking power is absolutely abyssmal.
i came across [these shimano mt200 hydraulic brake set](https://www.uaecycle.com/products/shimano-br-mt200-hydraulic-disc-brake-bicycle-oil-mountain-bike-brakes?variant=42339306832090), however it seems i will have to change my shifters. any recommendations for 8x3 shifters?

my cycle has tourney ty300 rd, 160mm front and back rotors, not sure about the other specs, but the pictures are exactly what my cycle has.
[image: current break system]
[image: tourney gear system of my cycle]

Comment: Note that mechanical disc brakes require regular adjustments to compensate for pad wear, it's their normal behaviour. Otherwise, product recommendation are off-topic here, so will probably be moderated. In 8 speed however, there's no compatibility issue, any shifter will work.

Comment: Echoing Renaud's comment. If you were to rephrase your question to ask if a specific set of bar end shifters would work, then you could recover this and get some good feedback. You might check with Shimano's compatibility cross-reference.  https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com

Answer (score 2):

Your bike has integrated brake levers with your shifters.  That is common on drop-bar road bikes with "brifters" but was far less common on flat bar bikes.

To be clear, your MT200 will come in a pre-bled kit with a brake lever on the end.  You only need shifters.

The downside of separate parts is that there will be an extra band clamp on your handlebars taking up a little more space, but you get much more flexibility.   You could even choose different styles - I have a friction front shifter and an indexed thumb rear shifter on one bike.

The old shifters need to come off, but they're still functional so store them or hand off to a local bike fixup/cooperative.

Any derailleur shifter that is 8 speed left or 3 speed right hand will work fine.  The exception would be anything labelled NEXUS or ALFINE - they're for internally-geared hubs which have different pull amounts.

Answer (score 1):

8 speed is quite easy.

Shimano make trigger shifters for 8x3

Sunrace make thumb shifters, trigger shifters, grip shifters.

SRAM make some shifters for 8sp but these are most often found to match their 1:1 rear derailleurs.

Choose the ones that suit what you are used to or the style you like. None of them are very expensive.